JFileChooser opening in background
I have a problem with the JFileChooser. When I call it in the main class, it opens in the foreground without any problems. But if I want to call it via another method, it opens in the background. How can I change this?
My current code looks like this:
public static void readBookCopyCSV() {

        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Open");
        fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("CSV file", "csv"));
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> bookData = new ArrayList<>();
        String filePath;

        int userSelection = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            filePath = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

{...}
            
        }
    }

I know it has something to do with a parent component and I tried to change some stuff but somehow it still does not work for me.
If i call BookCopy.readBookCopyCSV(); in the main.java it opens in the front. But i want the main class to only contain of a 'MenuHandler' method, which is located in another class. Now if i call the readBookCopyCSV method in the MenuHandler class it opens in the background.
My main class looks like this:
public class Library {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        MenuGetters.getMainMenu();
        MenuHandlers.handleMenuWithNumbers();
        //Book.readBookCSV(); 
    }

}

The commented Book.readBookCSV(); opens the file chooser in the front but that does not help me since the method should not be called in the main class. It should be called in the MenuHandlers class when the user wants to import a csv file for book copies. I have seen in another question that it works with a jframe but my program uses a cli and should not create a jframe.

So essentially your question is: What parameter to pass when calling method showOpenDialog of class JFileChooser You should pass an actual Component rather than null. You wrote (in your question): When I call it in the main class, it opens in the foreground without any problems. Are you also passing null when you call method showOpenDialog in the main class? [Edit] your question and post the code that calls showOpenDialog in the main class.

Do you have access to the parent jframe/window? fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null); you could put a reference to the window there. Also, can you make a minimal reproducible example? Maybe just create a JFrame and when you click a button it shows the dialog.

Best to create and post a decent [mre] with your question. Please read the link to see how doing this can help both you and us. If you have any questions about the link and its instructions, please ask.

But also, don't do fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);, don't pass in null into this parameter. Instead, pass in a reference to the parent JFrame, the program's main window.

There is no parent JFrame, the program runs over the CLI. However, if i want to import a csv file, the program should open the JFileChooser (ideally in the front)

But i want the main class to only contain of a 'MenuHandler' method, which is located in another class. - the code in that class probably requests focus on a component which takes focus away from the dialog. Without an [mre] there is not much we can do. This could also be a platform issue.

@David see my answer to the duplicate question.
